# ctrl+alt recognized as 'primary' on HP 8440p

Tags: linux, keyboard, xfce

I have a strange problem with my keyboard. I just wanted to set a keyboard shortcut on my xfce desktop (Settings Manager > Window Manager > Keyboard) but when I press

```
ctrl + alt + shift + up
```

(which is the shortcut I want) it prints

```
<Primary><Shift><Alt>Up
```

This is what happens exactly, when I put in the shortcut (new key --> new line):

```
key                     | shortcut shown by settings manager
Ctrl                    | Control_L
Ctrl + Alt              | <Primary>Alt_L
Ctrl + Alt + Shift      | <Primary><Alt>Shift_L
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Up | <Primary><Shift><Alt>Up
```

and if I press Shift before Alt:

```
key                     | shortcut shown by settings manager
Ctrl                    | Control_L
Ctrl + Shift            | <Primary>Shift_L
Ctrl + Shift + Alt      | <Primary><Shift>Meta_L
Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Up | <Primary><Shift><Alt>Up
```

Any idea what's wrong? My keyboard layout is set to `de-latin1-nodeadkeys` which should be correct.

*UPDATE April 2014:* I still have this issue. Now with [mate](http://mate-desktop.org/). I don't think it's a problem with the window manager. I think it's a problem with the driver or the hardware. Not that the hardware is faulty, I assume this is a wanted feature with this keyboard but I don't want it. My notebook is an *HP 8440p*.

Comment: One more hint: At home I have a docking station for my notebook with a PS2-Keyboard. With this keyboard I am able to **use** the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up shortcut (when configured correctly without `Primary`), although when I try to set the shortcut does the same as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone after upgrading the BIOS to Version 2.3.0.0 RevA.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue in Xfce4:

[Bug 8056 - Control modifier appears as Primary when setting shortcuts](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8056)

Comment: I don't use xfce no more. Now I still have this issue with Mate. I think it's a hardware or driver issue with my HP 8440p. I'll never buy a HP laptop again. Too many weird things like this.

Comment: My HP laptoṕ works fine with Linux. Many HP machines do.